# Installation interrupted by low battery

Tags: boot, system-installation

The Windows boot manager is showing Ubuntu + Windows options. However Ubuntu failed to install after one minute due to low battery.

Comment: If you're trying to remove the Ubuntu from the Windows boot loader try this link:
[http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=829466](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=829466)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your laptop is actually connected to external power.  If in doubt, remove the battery so that it cannot assume the battery is low.